# convert a character column into numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder why my conversion of the "t5" column was not successful--

The "t5" column is all characters, I want to convert it into a numeric column, leave non-numeric value as NA, named as "t5.num" in the tibble.

My code below:
first of all I assigned the name, then trying to mutate the column, but it did  not work--

```
d <- tibble(id = c(3, 7, 1, 10,100), t5 = c("10", "<1", "NA", "8","78"))
convert_column <- function(data, col_name) {
    new_col_name <- paste0(rlang::enquo(col_name),".num")
    data %>%
        mutate(new_col_name = as.numeric(!!col_name))
     }
d %>% convert_column("t5")
```

Can someone point out what is wrong with my code? thanks for your help!

Comment: So how do you expect `as.numeric` to treat `"<1"`? What numeric value would you expect?

Comment: "<1" should be NA and thank you for helping! I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `new_col_name` you don't need `enquo`. To assign `new_col_name` as name of the column use `!!`  + `:=`. As you are passing `col_name` as a string we need to convert it to symbol (`sym`) and then evaluate (`!!`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

convert_column <- function(data, col_name) {

   new_col_name <- paste0(col_name,".num")
   data %>% mutate(!!new_col_name := as.numeric(!!sym(col_name)))
}

d %>% convert_column("t5")

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     id t5    t5.num
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#1     3 10        10
#2     7 <1        NA
#3     1 NA        NA
#4    10 8          8
#5   100 78        78
```

Returns a warning while  converting "<1" to numeric before turning it to `NA`.

Comment: Thank you Ronak!
for the ":=", what does that mean? I would like to learn that part

Comment: @Flan When you use `mutate` as usual like `data %>% mutate(new_col_name = ...`. It creates a column with the name `new_col_name` but here since you want a column name with the value which is stored in `new_col_name` we use `:=` with `!!`.

Comment: got it. thanks again. I read the dplyr article and found what you said. I appreciate the answers.